# Katherine Anne Porter's "HE": What is He?

Tags: short-stories, character-analysis, katherine-anne-porter

I recently read Katherine Anne Porter's ["He"](http://fullreads.com/literature/he/), and, after reading it twice, am still left in the dark about one thing. It is said that "Rolls of fat covered Him like an overcoat", and he is portrayed as being physically larger than the average boy his size, remarkably strong and agile, yet slow to recover, and mentally limited. This might sound insensitive, but who is He, and what is going on with Him?

Comment: From the excerpt it seems clear it's the second son.  "Mrs. Whipple loved her second son, the simple-minded one, better than she loved the other two children put together. ..."

“You needn’t keep on saying it around,” said Mr. Whipple, “you’ll make people think nobody else has any feelings about Him but you.“    The use emphasized pronoun, rather than the name, might be so that the 'simple-minded' boy  doesn't realize he's is the topic of the discussion.

Comment: Is there a medical condition that he has, that can be described in today's medical terms?